# Qt 5.8, sqlite and deploy in windows

Tags: windows, qt, sqlite

Good day, i'm writing small project with Qt and sqlite. All works good in linux and windows with Qt framework installed. But when i trying to run it on pc without Qt - some problems appears.

That is how DB connected:
    databaseservice.h

```
class DatabaseService : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DatabaseService(QObject *parent = 0);

    ...

private:
    static QSqlDatabase db;

    ...
};


databaseservice.cpp

#include "databaseservice.h"

#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlQuery>

#include <QDebug>

QSqlDatabase DatabaseService::db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

DatabaseService::DatabaseService(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    db.setDatabaseName("1cprint.db");

    if(!db.open())  //true
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(0,
                      "Database init error",
                      "Database returns error - " + getLastError()); //Driver not loaded
        exit(1);
    }

    ...
}
```

When i'm trying to connect to DB, i recieve error "Driver not loaded". Google say that it can be plugin *qsqlite.dll* not found in correct path. I try to put this .dll on subdirectory *./sqldrivers/*, how it said in documentation; in *./plugins/sqldrivers/*, directly in project directory - all that has no result. Experimentally, i found that *qsqlite.dll* loaded from Qt framework directory (D:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\plugins\sqldrivers), but never from project dir. On pc with Qt framework - if i rename or move D:\Qt\5.9.1\mingw53_32\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlite.dll - program stops working.

I try many variants of *QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths, qApp->addLibraryPath*, but they all give no result.

Asking for idea.

Comment: Did you tried to put dll into the same directory level as the execution file?

Comment: yes, the same dir as executable, the .\sqldrivers and .\plugins\sqldrivers - no effect. C:\windows\system32 also tried.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it. Changed DatabaseService::db to non-static class member - and everything worked.